# How to hide the keyboard when user press return button?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView in my ViewController, When user press on that textView, the keyboard shows up. This is not the problem. My problem is: How to hide the keyboard when user press return button in the keyboard? I have tried some functions but apparently they worked only with UITextFields.

```
import UIKit

class NewNoteVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var newText: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        newText.text = "Start typing"
        newText.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        newText.tintColor = UIColor(red: 251/255, green: 140/255, blue: 139/255, alpha: 1)

            }

    /// setting placeholdere
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if newText.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
            newText.text = nil
            newText.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if newText.text.isEmpty {
            newText.text = "Placeholder"
            newText.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }

    /// limit characters
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let currentText = newText.text ?? ""
        guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }

        let changedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: text)

        return changedText.count <= 1000
    }

    /// hide keyboard when user touch outside screen
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    /// hide keyboard when user press return button


    @IBAction func backToMainPage(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Return character is _legal_ in a text view. No app in the world dismisses the keyboard when the user taps Return in a text view. Why be weird? If you wanted a one-line text entry where Return character is not legal, you should have used a text field.

Comment: i have gave the user the ability to edit the text he wrote previously, so while editing, the user may wanna get rid of the keyboard so he can see the hole text and preview it before save it. but keyboard cover part of the text.

Comment: Sure. But every text view out there gives the user some _other_ way to get rid of the keyboard. For example, the user can swipe down, or there's a button that closes the keyboard, or you add an accessory view. There are _lots_ of other ways to deal this, and they are all better than what you are proposing to do. Try looking at a few existing apps and see what they do, rather than making up some bizarre interface.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the reason might be to dismiss keyboard on return of a `UITextView` the simplest solution would be:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n" {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        {...}

    }
```